# OAuth exception - Error validating application. Invalid application ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, facebook-insights

Hi there i am keeping to getting this massege despite my app id is correct.

Here is my function:

```
 public void AuthorizeInsights()
    {
        string app_id = "my_app_id(client_id)";
        string app_secret = "my_app_secret";
        string scope = "public_profile,email,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_likes,ads_management";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
```

In my facebook  developers account page i see that my app id is correct and also the one i am inserting in the code.

Does someone has clue whats going on ?